# running react native in xcode, my error screen is white. Cannot see the error messages

Tags: react-native

When I am running react native in xcode, my error screen is white.  See screenshot.  If I highlight one of the rows, I can then see the text.  But this seems pretty odd.  Any ideas what would have caused this?  Wasnt always the case.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: post your code, will be helpful to debug

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same issue, and I used `git bisect` to find the commit where the problem was introduced. In my case I found that when we changed our launch screen from being a .XIB (LaunchScreen.xib) to a Storyboard (LaunchScreen.storyboard) it caused my error screen to look like yours, so reverting those changes fixed it for me.